# FactoryGirl, RSpec and mocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocking, rspec2, factory-bot

I use FactoryGirl in my tests, but the mocks and stubs are present as well (mock_model(User).as_null_object).
There is a strange behaviour: sometimes FactoryGirl can't create a record, because instead of normal date it inserts '#[User:0x827966c @name="User_1132"]' string into created_at and updated_at.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I can't parse/understand the phrase "it doesn't FG can't create a record" and don't know what FG means. Also, you need to show actual rspec output and show related code in order for anyone to reasonably help you.

Comment: Ok, I can parse/understand it now and I guess I should have figured out FG ;-), but I still need more info to be helpful.  Please show the full rspec output and related code (e.g. spec, model(s), etc.). Also, if you make a related update, would you please post a comment as well, just so I get a notification?